# QUIC Mode Detection in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome

I was wondering if anybody knew of a way to detect in Chrome whether QUIC mode is enabled? Or to disallow the site from using that protocol?

i ask as it sometimes causes my application to bug, and if it could be disabled for that website alone then that would make my site work better :)

Thanks!
Alex

Comment: Block port 80 UDP

Comment: Ahha, I guess I didn't know quick was on the same port as HTTP... Im using PeerJS to make two way communication between computers so HTTP is required. I guess if its on the same port there is no way. Thanks.

Comment: HTTP is TCP, QUIC is UDP.. you could just block the UDP traffic

Answer (score 0):

There are seval ways to block/disable QUIC. Here I can suggest some:

**Method 1**: Disable Experimental QUIC protocol on Google Chrome browser.

This can be done by opening Google Chrome, in the URL type [chrome://flags](http://chrome://flags). Look for Experimental QUIC protocol and disable it.

**Method 2**: Block UDP port 80 and port 443 on your custom firewall service

**Detect QUIC in Chrome**: 
If you want to see if your connection to Chrome uses QUIC, [here is a browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http2-and-spdy-indicator/mpbpobfflnpcgagjijhmgnchggcjblin) that can tell you. Moreover, you can find all the details about Chrome’s QUIC usage under the net-internals flag ([chrome://net-internals/#quic](http://chrome://net-internals/#quic)).